# Google Cloud no me permite crear mi primer proyecto con la cuenta de administrador

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Estoy intentando crear mi primer proyecto en google cloud con la cuenta de administrador de mi organización. Tengo el acceso al correo y claves del administrador y me estoy logeando con esa cuenta para poder hacerlo. El problema es que cuando doy click en crear nuevo proyecto recibo el siguiente error:

```
Se produjo un error durante la carga de /home/dashboard?project=woven-answer-302200&_ga=2.264464652.2067059090.1613688095-686096735.1602770205&authuser=1.

Te falta al menos uno de los siguientes permisos necesarios:
Proyecto

resourcemanager.projects.get
Verifica que el ID de proyecto es válido y que tienes permisos para acceder a él. Más información

Enviar comentarios
```

El detalle es que en mi panel de administración de recursos ya le di el permiso que me piden al recurso como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según he leído la función Administrador de IAM de proyecto debería otorgar la función de `resourcemanager.projects.get` y como pueden ver en la imagen el recurso rcv@.. que es el administrador lo tiene activado, sin embargo sigo intentando crear un proyecto nuevo y no me deja. Alguna idea para poder realizarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Como comentas, desde [IAM (Idnetity and Access Management)](https://cloud.google.com/iam) puedes asignar los permisos, veo que tienes asignado el de "Creador de Proyectos" pero es muy importante como comenta el mensaje:

> Verifica que el ID de proyecto es válido y que tienes permisos para
> acceder a él. Más información

**Verificar el proyecto donde se registro el permiso**, puedes seleccionarlo donde indica la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Es importante que antes de iniciar asegures iniciar una sesión en el navegador con el usuario, ya que si en la misma sesión cambiaste de usuario en ocasiones Google no te permite realizar modificaciones.